# How can I make scan-build follow __attribute__((cleanup))?

Tags: c, clang, raii, clang-static-analyzer

I have a (comically) simple program that uses Clang (or GCC)'s `__attribute__((cleanup))` machinery to automatically free memory:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void free_memory(void * mem) {
    void ** actual = (void**) mem;
    printf("freeing %p\n", *actual);
    free(*actual);
}

#define autofree __attribute__((cleanup(free_memory)))

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    autofree char * str = calloc(51, sizeof(*str));
    printf("str lives at %p\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled (simply with `clang file.c`), `free_memory` appears to be called as expected:

```
$ ./a.out
str lives at 0x1e2b2a0
freeing 0x1e2b2a0
```

However, `scan-build` still reports a potential leak:

```
$ export CC=clang
$ scan-build $CC test.c
file.c:15:5: warning: Potential leak of memory pointed to by 'str' [unix.Malloc]
    return 0;
    ^~~~~~~~
```

Is there something I can do to either suppress *exactly* this false positive or cause `scan-build` to follow through the `__attribute__((cleanup))` to the `free` call?

Comment: `scan-build` is a static analyzer and it does not observe any direct call to `free_memory`. And I would guess that it is not capable of deducing this from the gcc/clang-specific attributes.

Comment: _Side note:_ since `mem` is `void *`, the `(void **)` cast is unnecessary.

Comment: Apparently this is a [known false positive.](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3888#c14) The last time someone said they were looking at it was in 2014, which... doesn't bode well for it being fixed anytime soon.

Comment: Note conversation for the above bug continues at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/4260